# Why is F-score called "F-score"?

Tags: terminology, precision-recall, harmonic-mean

All other algorithm scores have names that make sense, but the F-score is just "F". Was the letter chosen at random?

Comment: 'all other algorithm scores have names that make sense' what sense would you give to the 'z'-score ? the 't'-score ?

Comment: It would be helpful if you made explicit in your question that you are asking for the F1 score, the harmonic mean of precision and recall, as people are answering about something completely different.

Comment: I think you mean F-measure and not score

Comment: @Cybercop I think both names are in widespread use. For what it's worth, the wikipedia article is called "[F1 score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score)" but lists "F-score" and "F-measure" as alternative names. Obviously we can't do a google n-gram search to establish which is more common, since the result is contaminated by the other type of [F-score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-test), which makes this question text rather ambiguous until you look at the tags that have been used!

Comment: -1 for being unclear exactly what "F-score" is being asked about, not even providing any context clues.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When F-scores are used on tests and the null hypothesis is true, F-scores (usually) follow an [F-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-distribution), which [is said](http://www.randomservices.org/random/special/Fisher.html) [to be named](http://courses.education.illinois.edu/EdPsy580/lectures/7ChiSq_Fdist_05_online.pdf) after [Ronald Fisher](http://courses.education.illinois.edu/EdPsy580/lectures/7ChiSq_Fdist_05_online.pdf), who developed its main applications - notably ANOVA.

Comment: I have a feeling that the OP is referring to [this F-score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score), not [that F-score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-test). Unfortunately the only clue for that is in the tags that have been used, not the question text...

Comment: @Silverfish You may be right. Another answer on that F-score would be interesting, too.

Answer (score 3):

If the "F-score" you're referring to is [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score) then according to these [lecture notes](https://www.cs.odu.edu/~mukka/cs795sum09dm/Lecturenotes/Day3/F-measure-YS-26Oct07.pdf) the answer appears to be that it is an accident of history.

> There is one thing that remains unsolved, which is why the F-measure is
>   called F. A personal communication with David D. Lewis several years ago
>   revealed that when the F-measure was introduced to MUC-4, the name was
>   accidentally selected by the consequence of regarding a different F function in van Rijsbergen’s book as the definition of the “F-measure”.